# ValueError: time data does not match format (convert part of string to time)

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

I have data that is formatted like DDHHMM (day hour minutes), for example 120630. So the 12th at 06:30. I want to extract only the hour and minutes and convert it to a time object. Is this possible. I get the following error.

```
time = datetime.strptime(column[3], '%H:%M') #data is from CSV

ValueError: time data '120630' does not match format '%H:%M'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to parse the datetime string in the format it currently is using [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html), and then convert the datetime object to the format you want using [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html):

```
 datetime.strptime('120630', '%d%H%M').strftime('%H:%M')
# '06:30'
```